# Cylinder’s kinetic energy and the arc-length

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A uniform cylinder of mass m and radius r rolls without slipping on a parabolic surface which $y=kx^2$

[image]

then how to write cylinder’s kinetic energy by arc-length $l$. since it's not a circular surface with constant $R$， I don't know how to work out kinetic energy in this case only by arc-length.
Should arc-length be ${\theta\times}kx^2$ here?

Comment: I'm sorry but since friction does no work WET is conserved and K.E only depends on the vertical height, have I misunderstood something? Are you specifically asking rotational kinetic energy or translational?

Comment: @JustJohan I also tring to get that point, the question also gives that the kinetic energy looking for is in form $T=km(l\dot)^2$, where k is constant and $(l\dot)$ is the derivative of arc-length l

Answer (score 0):

To get you started.

Start with $dl^2=dx^2+dy^2$, take the square root and factor out $dx$.  You  can calculate
$\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Integrate to get $l$ in terms of $x$ and use the $y(x)$ equation to get $l$ in terms of $y$.  Use the potential and kinetic energy equations from there.